# Passing additional parameters to dbConnect function for JDBCDriver in R

Tags: java, r, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to `HiveServer2` via `JDBC` drivers from `R` using `RJDBC` package. I have seen a broad explanation on passing additional arguments to `dbConnect` wrapper for various `drivers`([What arguments can I pass to dbConnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119142/what-arguments-can-i-pass-to-dbconnect)), but there appear that situation with `JDBCDriver` is a bit tricker than for other drivers. I can connect to `HiveServer2` under this specific URL adress `url = paste0("jdbc:hive2://", host = 'tools-1.hadoop.srv', ":", port = 10000, "/loghost;auth=noSasl")` . The correspoding code works and enables me to write statements on `Hive` from `R`

```
library(RJDBC)
dbConnect(drv = JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
                     classPath = c("/opt/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.0.0-standalone.jar",
                                   "/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar",
                                   "/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar"),
                     identifier.quote = "`"), # to juz niekoniecznie jest potrzebne
          url = paste0("jdbc:hive2://", host = 'tools-1.hadoop.srv', ":", port = 10000, "/loghost;auth=noSasl"),
          username = "mkosinski") -> conn
```

I am wondering if there is a way to pass arguments such as database name (`loghost`) or a no_authentication_mode (`auth=noSasl`) to `...` in `dbConnect` such that I could only specify standard URL address (`url = paste0("jdbc:hive2://", host = 'tools-1.hadoop.srv', ":", port = 10000)`) and somehow pass  the rest of parametrs like this

```
library(RJDBC)
dbConnect(drv = JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
                     classPath = c("/opt/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.0.0-standalone.jar",
                                   "/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar",
                                   "/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar"),
                     identifier.quote = "`"), # to juz niekoniecznie jest potrzebne
          url = paste0("jdbc:hive2://", host = 'tools-1.hadoop.srv', ":", port = 10000),
          username = "mkosinski", dbname = "loghost", auth = "noSasl") -> conn
```

But the second approach doesn't look to work, despite the various combinations of names and values of additional arguments I try.

**Does anyone know how to pass additional arguments to DBI::dbConnect through `...` parameter for `JDBCDriver`?**

Comment: Actually the URL could get as complicated as `jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;principal=hive/_HOST@<REALM>;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=<trust_store_path>;trustStorePassword=<trust_store_password>;transportMode=http;httpPath=<http_endpoint>` with Kerberos authentication and HTTPS transport with dummy SSL certificates. And even worse when throwing High Availability based on ZooKeeper quorum (that's not a joke, we have all these in Prod...)

Comment: I get it @SamsonScharfrichter :) . That's quite interesting. But what is the solution to my question? How can I pass those params?

Comment: I've no idea if, and how, you can pass all these URL options/parameters as JDBC parameters. The SSL options are actually used by the driver so they probably have to be set on the URL; the database can be changed dynamically at any time using a *statement* (i.e. `use MY_DB`); for the rest... did you try to connect with DBVisualizer or a similar tool, then check the list of JDBC params and their default values?

Comment: I don't think you pass it as `JDBC` parameters, but as `dbConnect` parameters on `JDBCDriver` . I haven't heard about DBVisualizer, but I'll google it out :)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I've found a list for supported drivers https://www.dbvis.com/doc/database-drivers/ - do you think the H2 driver correspond to the HiveDriver/HiveServer2?

Comment: By the way I just checked on my PC and... there are no pre-defined Database Properties for Hive. Sorry, that won't help :-(

Comment: *[Edit]* Nope. H2 is a fork from HypersonicSQL (HSQL). DBVis has no predefined settings for "Hive" and they don't provide a driver *(too many differences between versions and distros)*; you must drop the JARs on your PC and use [Tools][Driver Manager] menu to bind them to a custom "Hive" entry. Then you can create a Connection based on that driver (using "Database URL" settings).

Comment: How have you checked that `... there are no pre-defined Database Properties for Hive` ? And you mean in HypersonicSQL or dbConnect / JDBC ?

Comment: But there was a link to setting with hiveser2: https://github.com/cyanfr/dbvis_to_hortonworks_hiveserver2/wiki/How-I-Connected-DBVisualizer-9.2.2-on-Windows-to-Hortonwork-HiveServer2

Comment: In DbVisualizer 9.2.10 there were some Hive specific fixes and improvements (https://www.dbvis.com/doc/relnotes/?version=9.2.10). Please note that Hive is still not an officially supported database in DbVisualizer .

Comment: try to use RJDBC. works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059378/postgres-db-cant-connect-to-r-with-rjdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the author's answer: https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/31#issuecomment-173934951

> Simply anything - all that dbConnect does is to collect whatever you
>   pass (including ...) and collect it all into a property dictionary
>   (java.util.Properties) that is passed to the driver's connect()
>   method. So any named argument you pass is included. So the only
>   special argument is url which is passed directly, everything else is
>   included in the properties. How that gets interpreted is out of
>   RJDBC's hands - it's entirely up to the driver.

Answer (score 0):

there you can use the full url

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("org.postgresql.Driver","C:/R/postgresql-9.4.1211.jar")
con <- dbConnect(drv, url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname", user="<user name>", password="<password>")
```